# How to upgrade to Emacs 24.1?

Tags: emacs

Emacs 24.1 was released recently, and I'm wondering what the recommended way of upgrading Precise's Emacs to it is. I know of the [snapshot PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs), but I'd like the final, stable version. I've found [a suggestion to install it manually](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1999720), but I'd like to use apt if at all possible.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

By now [Cassou's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs) offers not only an emacs-snapshot but also an emacs24 package which provides the current stable version of Emacs 24.

[ppa:cassou/emacs [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use and still use Emacs 24.1, you could package emacs 24.1 taking the official emacs 24.1 sources. That'd be a steep learning curve if you are new to packaging and haven't packaged anything at all. So your best bet would be to use the emacs from the PPA or wait till some one packages the stable version. The emacs-snapshot build on 10th or 11th June 2012 will be the one corresponding to the stable release. Don't be fooled by the name 'emacs-snapshot', it will still be the stable emacs 24.1

Update: If you have Ubuntu 12.10, it includes Emacs 24.1 in its repositories. You can install them.