# How do I get emacs 24?

Tags: 12.04, emacs, backport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upgrade to Emacs 24.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149562/how-to-upgrade-to-emacs-24-1)

`emacs24` seems to bring quite a lot of minor improvements over the last version. I know there are already ppa's to easily install it but are there any chances that it will be backported to ubuntu `12.04`? where should I make a request or should I make a request for this?

also does anyone know what version is shipping with `12.10`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to install the quantal emacs24 release on 12.04 :

```
sudo -s
cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list-original
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted multiverse universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
aptitude update
aptitude install emacs24
cp /etc/apt/sources.list-original /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: I'm guessing this adds quantal repos to `12.04` which sounds even more dangerous than adding a ppa. Anyway I had tried installing from the ppa, broke my packages while removing `emacs23` and then fix it somehow using `aptitude`. Now it seems to be working, thanks..